# Match an 11 digit Australian ABN with indeterminate non-repeated seperators

Tags: regex

How can I match exactly 11 digits (an Australian ABN) where any of the pairs of digits may or may not be separated by any **single** non alphanumeric character (eg. a hyphen, period or any whitespace including new lines)?

I tried `(\d\W*?){11}` but this matches multiple "separators".

The regex should match all of these ...

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
11111111111
1-1111111111
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

but none of these

```
1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1--1111111111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex allows any number of non-word chars (via `*`), and also allows non-word characters at the end (the last group may have them).

You want 10 groups of a digit followed by an optional non-digit, followed by a digit:

```
^(\d\D?){10}\d$
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/PPyyTM4lMm), which passes your examples.

If you want to restrict what separators may be, for example only dot, whitespace or dash, use a character class for the separators:

```
^(\d[.\s-]?){10}\d$
```

Note that `\s` (whitespace) includes newline characters.

Comment: Its quicker by about %20 if you require the lone digit first. `^\d(\D?\d){10}$`

Answer (score 0):

G'day from Bris-vegas!  The ABN that I have isn't in that format.  It looks like this:  `## ### ### ###`

There is also a formula for mathematically verifying a valid ABN (not to mention you can do a search on their site), you can see [here](https://abr.business.gov.au/HelpAbnFormat.aspx).

I have created a new pattern that matches your sample inputs, plus the format that I am suggesting (and it's a little bit more efficient than the other suggested patterns).

```
^(?:\d-?\d{10}|\d(?:[ \.]?\d){10})$
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/j60by9/1)